# How to run Julia codes with a windows10 machine in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, julia

I want to run some codes with the help of Jenkins. OS is win10
Are there any tutorials on this issue? I searched around and couldn't find it.

I tried this command but failed.

```
cd E:\\sim_1\scripts
set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=8
julia E:\\sim_1\scripts\main.jl
```

told me julia is not a command. but it works on CMD.

Comment: jenkins does not always use the same PATH envirionmental variable as CMD.  Try specifying the full pathname of julia.

Comment: Or write your commands out to a bat file and execute the bat file.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. I posted a link that solves this problem but it has been folded:(